# How do I resolve "%1 is not a valid Win32 application"?

Tags: .net, asp.net, configuration, 64-bit, win64

**Environment:**
Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise 64bit, SP2
.NET framework is supposedly installed (2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 SP1)

I say "supposedly" because they are listed as installed under Add/Remove programs. I'm not sure it's *properly* installed, because the "ASP.NET" tab isn't added to any of the sites in IIS.

In the IIS Web Service Extensions section, I have both "ASP.NET v2.0.50727" (Allowed), and "ASP.NET v2.0.50727 (32-bit)" (Prohibited).

The site in question has script-execute enabled.

**Problem:**

I created a super-simple ASP.NET/C# website: Default.aspx with a label id="Label1", and a code-behind with: `Label1.text = "Hello World";` and the error I'm getting is:

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried running:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

from the command line?

Comment: After some Googling, I found that I have 2 copies of this exe, one in Windows\...\Framework\ and one in ...\Framework64\. Running the one in Framework64 says IIS is in 32 bit mode & not compatible, so I used the other one. Executed successfully, but now I don't even get the same error, just a 404.

Comment: After a server reboot, I finally got the standard .NET error page, which led me to figure out that the folder needed to be defined as its own application in IIS. After I did that, everything seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: But for what it's worth, I still don't have an ASP.NET tab for any sites in IIS.

Comment: From the command line? Do you mean specifically the Visual Studio command prompt?

Answer (score 6):

Also check your application pool. In a 64-bit environment, you may need to set "Enable 32-bit applications" in Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had "%1 is not a valid Win32 application." error message because my PATH environment variable was messed up as well. It included this garbage from a python install:

```
%PYTHON_HOME%;
%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had "%1 is not a valid Win32 application." error message because my PATH environment variable was messed up. Well, more specifically, the PATH itself had nothing wrong with it. Instead, I had accidentally created a file named "C:\Program" that was used instead of "C:\Program Files\" for path lookup. 
The accidental creation of "C:\Program" was a result of calling Notepad++ on the command line for C:\Program Files\test.txt (without quotation marks), so Notepad++ thought I was trying to edit a file called "C:\Program" and created the file for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 64 Bits.

The fusion log is not of any help here, and it turned out that in my case there was a third party assembly that was referencing a 32 Bits only assembly or native dll. (Xceed to be precise)

To find which assembly is being loaded by the 64 bits runtime :

- Attach the VS2008 debugger on *w3wp.exe* process that matches your application pool
- Intercept all exceptions (Menu Debug / Exceptions / check all "*Common Language Runtime Exceptions*").
- Make sure your application is reloaded completely (by modifying the web.config, for instance).
- When the *System.BadImageFormatException* exception is raised, look for a assembly name in the stack trace viewer window.

Remember that all assemblies placed in the bin directory are loaded, regardless of their actual implication in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.  I deployed an .EXE to a Windows 2003 that doesn't support .NET 4.5.  I rebuilt the program with .NET 4 and it worked.

Comment: Here is the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455855/exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-on-windows-xp/16460035#16460035