# Error while running mysql2 in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

having sorted this error -

[Ruby mysql2 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936523/ruby-mysql2-error)

I now am recieving this error message -

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

Any ideas guys?

Cheers
Martin

Comment: feels like you have some space characters on the file path while calling the application

Comment: The application runs in the Netbeans ruby console so all the file paths should be fine... what do you mean specifically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185042/how-do-i-resolve-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple download **libMySql.dll** from [here](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/), and then put it in ruby\bin.

Comment: I have already done that and I still recieve the same issue - I ma using windows 7, latest mysql server and latest mysql2 - Any other ideas? - Martin

Comment: After your advice I managed to sort it, your method caused an error stating it needed from the C connecter version 6 of the libmysql.dll file so I installed that and I am sorted! Thank for the help, Martin